# How to show an image from an image inputstream in Birt?

Tags: jfreechart, birt

I am using [birt](/questions/tagged/birt) to develop some reports,I want to display some pie charts in the [birt](/questions/tagged/birt) pdf report,I found the birt chart function is not very flexiable,so I want to use [jfreechart](/questions/tagged/jfreechart) to generate an image and show it in the report instead. Now I have a question: **can we show image in [birt](/questions/tagged/birt) with the image inputstream,so that the image do not need to be generated and store in some place?**
I know I can generate the image into a jpg file and store it in some place ,then I can access it birt report via the location of this image file.But if I do as that ,each time when we view the birt report ,it will generate a new image file,I do not want to generate so much files.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions.

As you said, you can save the charts as files.
I do this in a report where I generate dozens of control charts (German: "Regelkarten"). To tidy up after the report has finished, I add the generated file names to a list, then I delete the files in the list in the report's afterRender script like this.

```
var images = vars["images"];
for (var i=0; i<images.size(); i++) {
    var fname = images.get(i);
    if (new java.io.File(fname)['delete']()) {
        log.debug("Temp. image file removed: " + fname);
    } else {
        log.error("Could not delete temp. image file " + fname);
    }
}
```

Note: This is OK for generating PDF or Word, but probably it wouldn't work for HTML.

In my case, I did this because I could check the generated charts outside of BIRT by just commenting out the clean up routine.

The other option is to generate a `byte[]`. BIRT complains in the log file then (Rhino, something about unknown type mapping Java<->Javascript), but it works.
I never have used this with JFreeChart, but that's how we do it for generating DataMatrix ("2D-Barcode") with an ancient commercial Java library from a company called "ID Automation".

The image item references `row["dataMatrix_AuftID"]`, which is defined as type: `Java Object`, expression: `barcode.dataMatrix(row["AUFT_ID"],70,70,80,0.03)`

The function `barcode.dataMatrix` in our Javascript wrapper library for the Java library calls the Java library. Its last few lines look like this, which should give you an idea for your case:

```
    var image = new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(siz.width, siz.height, t);

    // get graphic context of image
    var imgGraphics = image.createGraphics();

    // paint DataMatrix in graphics context of image
    bc.paint(imgGraphics);

    // get the image's bytes in PNG format
    var baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
    javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
    var bytes = baos.toByteArray();

    return bytes;
```

As a side-note, for a proof of concept I showed that it is also possible to generate SVG in memory and use it with BIRT. Never used this in production, however.

Comment: thank you very much for answering it ,I will have try and tell you the result later.

Comment: thanks hvb,why do you wrote never use it in production? is it cost lots of memory resource?

Comment: I didn't write "never use it", but "I never used it". I just meant that I don't have much experience with it.